# Smooth 3d scene rotation like Blender's

Tags: rotation, blender

I'm working on an application that renders a 3D world and would like to implement a rotation of the scene like Blender does it. You can see it in video here: https://youtu.be/ILqOWe3zAbk?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6&t=66 (I'm not talking about the interaction with gyzmo but the way the camera rotates while the user drags the mouse)

I have implemented a trackball rotation but it has two aspects that bothers me:

1. the scene does not rotate enough (or fast enough),
2. the rotation stops as you get near the edge of the window.

For the first point, simply multiplying the angle of rotation does not solve the problem. In fact it creates another one: when the angle goes beyond 1 radian then the rotations are terribly jerky, even a small variation of the mouse cursor creates discontinuities (jumps) in the rotation. I have tried different factors to multiply the angle but I didn't get any good results: once you reach 1 radian, the discontinuities appear.

For the second point, I imagine this is the expected behaviour of the trackball method but in the Blender's options you can clearly see that it uses a trackball method to rotate the view.

I will post some code if I need to but since it works as expected as long as the absolute value of the angle of rotation is below 1 radian, I think the problem is that Blender uses a variation of the trackball.

Answer (score 0):

For one, rotating more makes it faster, to make it smoother, you need to draw more frames. Just drawing at 25 degrees and then 65 degrees makes a sudden jump, but also drawing in-between frames at 35,45 and 55 degrees gives a smoother movement. The frame rate the scene draws at determines how many between frames you can draw to transition from the start to the end positions. Jerky movement would indicate that your main loop is too slow, you need a comfortable rotation speed that feels like it matches the mouse movement, then speed up the frame rate so that your main loop is updating enough times to make the transition smooth enough.

For two, blender has an option in Input preferences called [Continuous Grab](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/editors/preferences/input.html?highlight=continuous%20grab), you may notice that it makes the cursor jump to the opposite side of the window. Maybe you could start [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_event_system.c$1306) and follow what it does. Notice that when dragging a UI widget for numbers, the cursor gets hidden and returns to its start position on release.